# Extjs improve performance of treenode.appendchild()

Tags: extjs

I am using Extjs 4.2.1. I have a bufferedrenderer tree grid, where the requirement is to append many children to specific node.

**Here is my code**

```
Ext.suspendLayouts();
Ext.getCmp('bufferedTree').getStore().suspendEvents();
for(var i=0;i<node.length;i++){
    node1.appendChild(node[i]);
    nodesArray.push(node[i]);
}
node1.appendChild(nodesArray);
Ext.resumeLayouts(true);
Ext.getCmp('bufferedTree').getStore().resumeEvents();
```

- node is selected nodes to append
- node1 is parent to which nodes to be appended.

Its working fine, but the problem is when number of nodes to append increases, time required to appendchild increases.

Any solution to reduce time?

Answer (score 2):

Each node addition is going to trigger a layout update, which is going to have a cost with performance. So the more you append, the greater the cost.

If you look at the docs for [appendChild()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.NodeInterface-method-appendChild), you'll notice that you can append either a single node, or an array of nodes. Instead of appending at each iteration of the loop, I would create an array of all the nodes you want to append, and then append them as one call. That way, the layout updates will only happen once, instead of once per node addition. This will almost certainly improve the performance.

Comment: Hi I have tried creating array of nodes, and then calling appendchild method only once, but still it takes 40 seconds to append 200 children .

Comment: Can you provide a repro case?